# Term to contrast multiplicative factors greater/less than one?

Tags: terminology

Are there adjectives to distinguish positive real numbers/functions depending on whether they are greater/equal/less than one? I have a nagging feeling that I already know the answer but can't remember.

I am expecting something along the lines of *subunitary*, *unitary*, or *superunitary*. Indeed, [one source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subunitary) defines subunitary as "of a magnitude less than one unit", which is what I want. Yet, I have not encountered the term despite running into the concept all the time. Would you understand the meaning of these terms without an explanation?

Comment: None that you can expect your readers to know. There is "unimodular" (meaning $|a|=1$) but this is somewhat different from what you asked.

Comment: Work with the logarithm, thereby reducing it to a previously solved case ("positive/zero/negative").

Comment: Why do you need special terms? Just be clear.

Comment: Why use three words if one would do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I would not understand the meaning of subunitary and/or superunitary without an explanation.